# 1004 Error on simple Sub

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, global

I'm having a 1004 error in the code below. Its such as simple routine, I can't figure out what's wrong. This is only one sub of many in Module 1. Note that UserForm2's code works fine when I run it from the forms Sub's. But when I call it from here, I get the 1004 error. I don't really understand what causes that error. Help appreciated. Note that ChosenString and Report is a Public variable. You have several 1004 error entries, but I can't find one that fits this problem. Error is on UserForm2.Show.

```
Sub ChooseReport()
' Display a selection box of reports and run the report
'
        ChoseCancel = 0
        Sheets("Codes").Activate
        UserForm2.Show       ' Displays selection box of reports
'
' If the Cancel button was selected, exit the sub
        If ChoseCancel = 1 Then
            Sheets("Reports").Activate
            Exit Sub
        End If
'
' Trim returned value of the comma
    StringLength = Len(ChosenString)
    Report = Left(ChosenString, StringLength - 2)
'
End Sub
```

This is my UserForm2 Code. It works fine.

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
' Fill the list box with appropriate values
'
    UserForm1.ListBox1.ListStyle = fmListStylePlain
    Sheets("Codes").Activate
    Range("O4").Select
'
' Fill List box with appropriate cells entries for Reports
     With ListBox1
         Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
              .AddItem ActiveCell.Value
              ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
         Loop
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Might not have pasted right. This was my first post..

Comment: Do you have a `UserForm_Initialize` sub-procedure, or any classes which use the events of this UserForm?

Comment: Please either add the code from the `Userform_Initialize` and/or `Userform_Activate` events from UF2, or change your VBE options to break in class modules, run the code again and then tell us the actual error line.

Comment: Error line is UserForm2.Show, as provided in the first paragraph.

Comment: Strangely, UserForm_Initialize is now failing with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I had copied the code from UserForm1, and hadn't changed a reference to UserForm1 to UserForm2. My error went away.